# UIBrowsableContentSupportsImmediatePlayback equivalent?

Tags: android, android-auto

For iOS audio apps supporting CarPlay, we have `UIBrowsableContentSupportsImmediatePlayback` to open app directly in Now Playing screen.

Is there anything like it for Android Auto?